# OpenCV encode CHW(Channel, Height, Width) format image failed

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV python API, the image is HWC at first(by default) and I use

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
image_bytes = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1]
```

it works well, the `img` variable is an ndarray with HWC(height, width, channel) format, with shape [224, 224, 3]

Then I transpose the image to CHW(channel, height, width) format and would result in [3, 224, 224] ndarray because my machine learning model takes this shape of array, but the model is on another machine, so I want to use encoding to reduce the size, but another machine is reserved for purely machine learning, so I do not want to do transpose on that machine, I want to get the ndarray I need as soon as decoded. So I do it using

```
img = img.transpose((2, 0, 1))
image_bytes = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1]
```

And it raised error

```
Traceback:
  File "..."
    image_bytes = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1]
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:871: error: (-215:Assertion failed) channels == 1 || channels == 3 || channels == 4 in function 'imencode'
```

Does image encoding support CHW? How to do it correctly?

Comment: Have you considered on how the imencode function would know that the image is in HWC or CHW format?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Seems it takes the first dimension as channel now. The code is cpp native, I have to go to the source code.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy The code is `#define CV_MAT_CN(flags)        ((((flags) & CV_MAT_CN_MASK) >> CV_CN_SHIFT) + 1)`. The `flag` in comment is dimension, so it seems only other 2 variables matters

Comment: What is CHW format and who wants/needs it, please? You seem to assume you can swap the order of the axes in an image arbitrarily which makes no sense. Almost no image formats (JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP, TGA, PNM) apart from TIFF, allow anything other than 1, 3 or 4 channels.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is the layout of channel, height, width. Added in description

Answer (score 0):

No normal (regular) image formats support CHW encoding. They are pretty much all predicated on there being 1, 2, 3 or 4 channels in the final dimension as follows:

- 1-channel: presumed greyscale or depthmap
- 2-channel: either greyscale+alpha or greyscale+depthmap
- 3-channel: either RGB or CMY
- 4-channel: either RGBA or RGB+depthmap or CMYK

The notable exception is TIFF which supports a larger number of channels in some variants, but it is my impression this is not that widely understood by image viewers.

Comment: I think maybe my expression is not so good. I mean, encode CHW layout image, the encoding is still RGB channel, but the channel is at the first dimension at the ndarray layout. Hope this explanation is right? Do you have any suggestions to edit this question?

Comment: The problem is not that the channel is first. The problem is that the width is last. So it is going to get upset as soon as the width exceeds 4 pixels.

Comment: I do not know the terminology upset, basically does it mean it is not reasonable to encode CHW memory layout?

Comment: I don't believe it is reasonable, but you haven't actually given any reason/grounds for wanting it that way or said what application wants the data that way. Nor do I see what is wrong with simply re-ordering it like you already demonstrated. There may be some good reason and thousands of people doing it every day, but I don't know that...

Comment: I have added the reason, please check if a reasonable scenario